Problemas en laravel 10 con dompdf con estilos de letra
estoy haciendo una pagina web en laravel en la cual genero un pdf con los datos de un proyecto de universidad, el problema esta en que me dieron un formato especifico para generarlo y solo me falta que logre ponerse la fuente de poppins, pero no funciona
Algun experto que me pueda apoyar? hice este formulario como prueba pero no sirve, haciendo un documento html si lo agarra


Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Te sugiero leer Cómo preguntar para mejorar tu pregunta y que sea mejor recibida. También, aprovechar y hacer el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos. Y x lo de imagenes de codigo Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes… e Historias de terror para programadores. En fin... Probaste poner los estilos inline?
